# Embed a local html file in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, bokeh, reveal.js

I want to import [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/) interactive graphs in my [reveal.js](https://revealjs.com/#/) presentation.

### What I can do

1. I can embed html content inside reveal.js with an iframe:

```html
<iframe data-src="https://demo.bokeh.org/sliders" 
width="445" height="355" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" 
scrolling="no" style="border:3px solid #666; margin-bottom:5px; max-width:
100%;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

2. I can save a Bokeh plot in html format:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("/line.html")
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
show(p)
```

which result in a file `line.html` that I can see and interact with when I open it with my web-browser.

### What I can't do

Embed my `line.html`file inside reveal.js.

#### I tried:

1. `<iframe data-src="/Users/JohnDoe/line.html" width="945" height="555" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes" style="border:3px solid #666; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 600%;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`

   This result in the message `Cannot GET /Users/JohnDoe/line.html` displayed in my iframe.
2. `<iframe data-src="file:///Users/JohnDoe/line.html" width="945" height="555" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes" style="border:3px solid #666; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 600%;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`

   And nothing is displayed in the trame.

## What I want to do

I want that my .html file to be displayed in my iframe as it is working in 1. of the "What I can do" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reveal.js output is displayed from a local server of some kind, correct? AFAIK IFrames will not allow you to load from local files in that case. In general, you cannot load `file:\\` from `http:\\` because that would be a giant security hole. A solution would be to run a basic HTTP server to serve the Bokeh HTML files, e.g `python -m http.server` (or `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` for legacy Python 2) and have your IFrame load the Bokeh pages from the simple server.

Comment: Many thanks, it works. 

Although I'm mainly looking for a solid simplified workflow to work with interactive graphs (and drop beamer). Your solution add an extra layer of complexity :-( .

I will post an other question for best practice :-) .

Comment: There are other ways to embed Bokeh documents, but AFAIK you are always going to run into the same problem. If your slides are viewed from an HTTP url, then you aren't going to be able to load any local files. Can you add arbitrary files or directories to whatever server is serving the Reveal slides? That's probably your best option to avoid needing a second server.